# Need some help in converting VB.Net webservice SOAP method into C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have tried online converters but it omits   `<Serialization.XmlElement("binaryData", DataType:="base64Binary")>` in the below function call

```
  <WebMethod(), SoapHeader("Credentials", Direction:=SoapHeaderDirection.InOut)> _
            Public Function GetPDFArray(ByVal id As Integer) As <Serialization.XmlElement("binaryData", DataType:="base64Binary")> Byte()
```

Appreciate if someone can please help...

Answer (score 1):

In C#, you need to have the 'return' attribute before the method header:

```
[WebMethod(), SoapHeader("Credentials", Direction=SoapHeaderDirection.InOut)]
[return: Serialization.XmlElement("binaryData", DataType="base64Binary")]
public byte[] GetPDFArray(int id)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks you @Dave, it worked, much appreciated !

Comment: @MirAli: No problem - just realized I left out the 'WebMethod' and 'SoapHeader' attributes.